# Django + gunicorn + nginx: 502 bad gateway but sometimes only?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I recently decided to just give up on apache2 + mod_wsgi and give a try to gunicorn + nginx to run my Django App.

I followed those tutorials with no issue at all, on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 install:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file

I thought that everything would be fine, but when browsing my website, I noticed that from time to time a few pages did not display at all and just show a `502 Bad Gateway` error. Looking into the `error/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I only have errors like the following:

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

I have no clue on what it implies:

- why would it be my Django install, if I have no issues when running on localhost for instance?
- also: sometimes all pages work and display just fine; sometimes the sames pages will throw a 502 error :(
- how could I know what's wrong with my gunicorn install, if the issue comes from there? How to debug?

For you information:

---

#### /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

---

#### /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myself
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myself/django/myproject
ExecStart=/home/myself/django/myproject/venvprod/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject

```
server {
    server_name mysite.fr mysite.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myself/django/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mysite.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.fr mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

---

If anything else is needed, please just ask! My real issue is that **I have no idea how to find the problem**. What tool could I use?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

#### EDIT 1

I can confirm I do not have any error coming from my Django code. I logged everything as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/krazymax/debug-m2g.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

and I do not have any error logged in while browsing my website (with pages that always display, other that never display and some that sometimes display, sometimes don't display).

---

#### EDIT 2

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/ravidsrk/8431321), ie without using an intermediate sock file. No success, even if when executing `myvenv/bin/gunicorn -c myvenvprod/gunicorn_config.py myproject.wsgi` I am able to access my website (and not otherwise): I am still having my pages being displayed (or not) randomly. I really have no clue and it's official, this random behavior is driving me crazy!

Comment: having the same problem, it is driving me crazy. I get the 502 http error and gunicorn worker timeout only on some queries, and sometimes the query executes and updates the database, but i still get a 502 response and a gunicorn timeout

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means that there is not a "connection" between Nginx and Gunicorn, the problem is the socket file.

Run "/home/myself/django/myproject/venvprod/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000" and see the output.
This execute the gunicorn server with your Django process without demonize it.

Maybe there is an error in your Django code and the socket is not created correctly.
While Gunicorn is open try also to visit YOUR_IP:8888 (es. 52.45.241.21:8888) from your browser: do you see the website?

If you see some Python errors you should first debug your project with "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000".

The 0.0.0.0:8000 after runserver allows your site to be visited form an external browser (like -b 0.0.0.0:8000 option in Gunicorn)

Remember: before follow any tutorial on a Django project deploy check that the project works correctly on the machine using runserver

EDIT: Try also an easier tutorial like this: https://gist.github.com/ravidsrk/8431321

Hope this hepls! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not new in Django, as I have been working on my app for one year now. So, I am pretty familiar with `runserver`etc. The real issue is when deploying my app: I have no issues running it on my local machine with runserver (no errors), but I've got `502` errors when running on my server. And nothing in the logs can help me for now, except this `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`.

Comment: @KrazyMax I'm pretty sure the problem is the socket file, try to use a port like 127.0.0.1:8001 instead of a socket file, like in the tutorial linked. Maybe the www-data user hasn't the permissions for read the socket folder

Comment: I would like to try, but I am not sure how to on my distant server? It looks like your tutorial is made for local dev, not prod dev. Nothing is really explained, I don't understand why such IP is binded that way etc. It's difficult for me to apply it to my production environment actually!

Comment: There could be something regarding the permissions, however what's really weird is that the exact same page sometimes display correctly, sometimes not (with error 502). From that, it's hard for me to believe the issue comes from my Django code! It should always work, or never work but why that hybrid behavior?! :(

Comment: The tutorial is made for a common VPS with Debian/Ubuntu, it is like the tutorial of DigitalOcean. The IP is not binded. The only difference is that the socket will not be a .sock file but a localhost port. Nginx and Gunicorn will not comunicate writing/reading a .sock file but will comunicare on localhost port (like 127.0.0.1:8001 for example)

Comment: @KrazyMax If runserver displays the site correctly there are not problems with the code :) Read my previous comment ;)

Comment: Ok I'll give a shot with that then. First issue if I follow the tuto and do: `myvenv/bin/gunicorn --bind my.ip:8001`, I've got: `gunicorn: error: No application module specified.`. And I do `myvenv/bin/gunicorn --bind my.ip:8001 myproject/wsgi:application` throws a `No module named 'myproject/wsgi' error. Did you have the same feedback?

Comment: Gunicorn doesn't accept a filename (so you can't indicate a path), do the following: myvenv/bin/gunicorn --bind my.ip:8001 myproject.wsgi:application

Comment: If gunicorn continue to not find the module you need to add the module parent dir to the PYTHONPATH, if you project is under  /my/other/path/myproject for example use this: export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"

Comment: The command worked with your advice. I did everything as in this tutorial (remember: I am in prod), and now I can not connect at all to my website :( (in the error.log: `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`). The only things I changed are my python path, project path and `user = 'myself'`in `gunicorn_config.py`.

Comment: Also I'm https, I don't know if that matters or not. To be honnest, I started using gunicorn yesterday, still read dozens of pages on it, and I do not truly understand everything I do when following those kind of tutorials (I only understand the logic, not the little details)

Comment: try to remove http:// before proxy pass in the Nginx config file (so write this: proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000) and then restart Nginx

Comment: That throws an error when trying to restart Nginx (`invalid URL prefix`). I also tried to change the port (8000 instead of 8001), still not working, damn

Comment: Have you tried this for production? I made the conf back again, I will try to analyse my django error log, as it appears a few things are not working as expected in prod (a few var of my context do not seem to be readable?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178132/discussion-between-krazymax-and-odle098).

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem. i install Django, Gunicorn, nginx follow this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04
Sometime my website get slow and get 502 error. Especially when idle in a time and comeback. First click get 502, and then click twice the website run smoothly.
And i founded this: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-gunicorn/
in my case: i increase gunicorn and nginx timeout:

nginx:

```
location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    }
```

gunicorn service:

```
ExecStart=/home/myself/django/myproject/venvprod/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          --timeout 60 \
          myproject.wsgi:application
```

Comment: This did not work for me but a related solution did  I suspect there could be a bad interaction between nginx, gunicorn and postgres due to a bug in how gunicorn interprets upstream benign errors from postgres. I was also able to fix it by focusing on timeout, however, I instead added fail_timeout=10000000 to the server entry in the upstream block.  I discuss this in detail here: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2347#issuecomment-670797131

Answer (score 1):

After a thousand searches I found the solution to my problem.

I installed gunicorn in a virtual environment. I had to go to the installation folder /virtual/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn$ and modify the config.py file increasing the timeout time to 3000.